# Pandas insert value into dataframe with loc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is called dfDays that look like this:

```
siren   Groupe  nomination_frequence    demission_frequence depart_frequence    modification_frequence  deces_frequence confirmation_frequence  sansprecision_frequence nbJoursMoyenne  ecart_type  nbJoursDernierEvenementExtraction
0   XXX Dirigeants  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   None    NaN 2345
1   XXX Autres  2   0   2   0   0   0   0   191 270.586 1217
2   XXX Dirigeants  0   0   0   0   0   0   3   281 281 1283
3   XXX Dirigeants  2   2   0   0   0   0   0   61  86.7384 1583
4   XXX Dirigeants  1   1   0   0   0   0   5   93  136.118 1283
```

I'm adding into a new datadrame called dfNew the values of the dfDays but adding a category according to the "groupe"

Let's assume the final dataframe that I want to obtain is : (dont look at the values)

```
    siren   Dirigeants_nomination_frequence Dirigeants_demission_frequence  Dirigeants_depart_frequence Dirigeants_modification_frequence   Dirigeants_deces_frequence  Dirigeants_confirmation_frequence   Dirigeants_sansprecision_frequence  MembresDuConseil_nomination_frequence   MembresDuConseil_demission_frequence    ... mouvement_ecart_type    Dirigeants_nbJoursMoyenne   Dirigeants_ecart_type   Dirigeants_nbJoursDernierEvenementExtraction    Autres_nbJoursMoyenne   Autres_ecart_type   Autres_nbJoursDernierEvenementExtraction    MembresDuConseil_nbJoursMoyenne MembresDuConseil_ecart_type MembresDuConseil_nbJoursDernierEvenementExtraction
0   XXX 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 NaN NaN 2345.0  NaN NaN 0.0 NaN NaN 0.0
3   XXX 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 281.0   281.000000  1283.0  191.0   270.586195  1217.0  NaN NaN 0.0
11  XXX 2.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 61.0    86.738432   1583.0  NaN NaN 0.0 NaN NaN 0.0
16  XXX 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 93.0    136.118413  1283.0  NaN NaN 0.0 NaN NaN 0.0
```

Here is my code in order to do that:

```
liste_nom = ['nomination_frequence','demission_frequence','depart_frequence','modification_frequence','deces_frequence','confirmation_frequence','sansprecision_frequence',
             'nbJoursMoyenne','ecart_type', 'nbJoursDernierEvenementExtraction']

for index, row in dfDays.iterrows():
    #print(row)
    name = row['Groupe']
    siren = row['siren']
    index = dfRight[dfRight['siren'] == siren].index[0]

    print(dfNew.columns)
    for value in liste_nom:
        #print(row)
        #print(row[value])
        dfNew.loc[index, name + '_' + value] = row[value]
print(dfNew.columns)
```

My problem is that before using the first .loc with index my columns look like this in dfNew:

```
Index(['siren', 'Dirigeants_nomination_frequence',
       'Dirigeants_demission_frequence', 'Dirigeants_depart_frequence',
       'Dirigeants_modification_frequence', 'Dirigeants_deces_frequence',
       'Dirigeants_confirmation_frequence',
       'Dirigeants_sansprecision_frequence',
       'MembresDuConseil_nomination_frequence',
       'MembresDuConseil_demission_frequence',
       'MembresDuConseil_depart_frequence',
       'MembresDuConseil_modification_frequence',
       'MembresDuConseil_deces_frequence',
       'MembresDuConseil_confirmation_frequence',
       'MembresDuConseil_sansprecision_frequence',
       'Autres_nomination_frequence', 'Autres_demission_frequence',
       'Autres_depart_frequence', 'Autres_modification_frequence',
       'Autres_deces_frequence', 'Autres_confirmation_frequence',
       'Autres_sansprecision_frequence', 'mouvements_nbJoursMoyenne',
       'mouvement_ecart_type'],
      dtype='object')
```

But after I'm using .loc multiple time the column are swapped and look like this:

```
Index(['siren', 'Dirigeants_nomination_frequence',
       'Dirigeants_demission_frequence', 'Dirigeants_depart_frequence',
       'Dirigeants_modification_frequence', 'Dirigeants_deces_frequence',
       'Dirigeants_confirmation_frequence',
       'Dirigeants_sansprecision_frequence',
       'MembresDuConseil_nomination_frequence',
       'MembresDuConseil_demission_frequence',
       'MembresDuConseil_depart_frequence',
       'MembresDuConseil_modification_frequence',
       'MembresDuConseil_deces_frequence',
       'MembresDuConseil_confirmation_frequence',
       'MembresDuConseil_sansprecision_frequence',
       'Autres_nomination_frequence', 'Autres_demission_frequence',
       'Autres_depart_frequence', 'Autres_modification_frequence',
       'Autres_deces_frequence', 'Autres_confirmation_frequence',
       'Autres_sansprecision_frequence', 'mouvements_nbJoursMoyenne',
       'mouvement_ecart_type', 'Dirigeants_nbJoursMoyenne',
       'Dirigeants_ecart_type', 'Dirigeants_nbJoursDernierEvenementExtraction',
       'Autres_nbJoursMoyenne', 'Autres_ecart_type',
       'Autres_nbJoursDernierEvenementExtraction',
       'MembresDuConseil_nbJoursMoyenne', 'MembresDuConseil_ecart_type',
       'MembresDuConseil_nbJoursDernierEvenementExtraction'],
      dtype='object')
```

I dont understand how the use of .loc is able to swap the order of my columns ?
Thank's for reading.

Comment: It seems there is problem with duplicates. Can you change data sample for small dataframe - e.g. 5 rows and 3 columns with duplicates in `Groupe` column with desired output?

Comment: You mean like you would see 10 values for the groupe "Dirigeant" for instance ? please note that all 'siren' value are not duplicated it's only because I cant make this data public.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for reshape and then flatten `Multiindex` in columns by `map` with `join`:

```
print (df)
  siren      Groupe  nomination_frequence  demission_frequence
1     b      Autres                2.0000                  191
2     c  Dirigeants              281.0000                 1283
3     d  Dirigeants               86.7384                 1583
4     e  Dirigeants              136.1180                 1283
```

First filter columns by list:

```
liste_nom = ['nomination_frequence','demission_frequence', ...] + ['siren','Groupe']

df = df[liste_nom]

df = df.pivot(index='siren', columns='Groupe')
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
       nomination_frequence_Autres  nomination_frequence_Dirigeants  \
siren                                                                 
b                              2.0                              NaN   
c                              NaN                         281.0000   
d                              NaN                          86.7384   
e                              NaN                         136.1180   

       demission_frequence_Autres  demission_frequence_Dirigeants  
siren                                                              
b                           191.0                             NaN  
c                             NaN                          1283.0  
d                             NaN                          1583.0  
e                             NaN                          1283.0
```

but if get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

it means there are duplicates in columns pairs for new indexes and columns.

So need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with some aggregate function like `mean`:

```
print (df)
  siren      Groupe  nomination_frequence  demission_frequence
1     b      Autres                2.0000                  191 <-same b,Autres 
1     b      Autres                5.0000                   50 <-same b,Autres 
2     c  Dirigeants              281.0000                 1283
3     d  Dirigeants               86.7384                 1583
4     e  Dirigeants              136.1180                 1283

liste_nom = ['nomination_frequence','demission_frequence', ...] + ['siren','Groupe']

df = df[liste_nom]

df = df.pivot_table(index='siren', columns='Groupe', aggfunc='mean')
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
       demission_frequence_Autres  demission_frequence_Dirigeants  \
siren                                                               
b                           120.5                             NaN (191 + 50)/2 = 120.5  
c                             NaN                          1283.0   
d                             NaN                          1583.0   
e                             NaN                          1283.0   

       nomination_frequence_Autres  nomination_frequence_Dirigeants  
siren                                                                
b                              3.5                              NaN  
c                              NaN                         281.0000  
d                              NaN                          86.7384  
e                              NaN                         136.1180
```

But if need change columns names by swapping and sorting:

```
liste_nom = ['nomination_frequence','demission_frequence'] + ['siren','Groupe']
df = df[liste_nom]
df = df.pivot_table(index='siren', columns='Groupe', aggfunc='mean')
df = df.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
       Autres_demission_frequence  Autres_nomination_frequence  \
siren                                                            
b                           120.5                          3.5   
c                             NaN                          NaN   
d                             NaN                          NaN   
e                             NaN                          NaN   

       Dirigeants_demission_frequence  Dirigeants_nomination_frequence  
siren                                                                   
b                                 NaN                              NaN  
c                              1283.0                         281.0000  
d                              1583.0                          86.7384  
e                              1283.0                         136.1180
```

Comment: It's working there is no "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". But I would like to use loc because I need to input value like 0 sometime and NaN in some special case... do you see why it's getting my columns swapped ?

Comment: Check answer, I add solution for it.

Comment: For the use of LOC ?

Comment: I think `loc` here is not necessary, because need pivoting.

Comment: Ok thank's for the insight... But I need columns in a particular order how can I do that ?

Comment: You need create order in `liste_nom` and after subset `df = df[liste_nom]` order will be changed.